# Is it possible to model $n$ dimensions with $n$ greater than 3?

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question

I've recently started a self-study of linear-algebra and the inability to visualize $n$ dimensions where $n$ is greater than three has been brought to my attention. I was aware of this limitation, but I had never really thought about it until I had a look at $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector spaces. So my question is: have there ever been any notable attempts at modeling $n$ dimensions? Obviously through computers.

Comment: [It is not "obvious" to me that you would need a computer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. I've heard of this book, but I've never had a chance to read it.

Comment: Consider 2 dimensions, this is a plane and can be thought of as a number line for which each element is another number line.  Consider 3 dimensions, this could be thought of as a number line for which each element is a plane (a 2 dimensional object).  Consider 4 dimensions, this could be thought of as a number line for which each element is a 3-dimensional object.  Consider 5 dimensions, ...

Comment: "Visualizing a $4$-dimensional sphere is really quite easy.  Just start by visualizing an $n$-dimensional sphere, then choose $n=4$."

Comment: @gd1035 So I started drawing this out...and I literally don't know what I'm looking at anymore. Thank you for the visuals.

Comment: For larger n, geometric visualization is almost impossible.  When looking at such questions, direct analysis of arrays such as $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ is used.

Comment: Relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25983/intuitive-crutches-for-higher-dimensional-thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dimensions greater than $3$, I don't know how most people visualize this but for the space between points I think of a grid with the origin of a $3$ dimensional coordinate frame at every unit intersection.

This helps me in visualizing a line from say $(1,2,3,4)$ to $(3,1,-2,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which is indicated by the line between red dots in the diagram. This diagram is good for up to $\mathbb{R}^6$. After that I start imagining these grid frameworks located at each unit intersection on another larger grid and so on.

I can visualize every vector as a $3$D line but at different coordinate frame locations. I don't know whether this will help or confuse you.

[image]

Comment: Love your graphic!

Comment: This is actually really similar to the 4D graph I ended up with based on @gd1035 explanation, which is pretty crazy.